# Adjusting position of CSS overlay according to screen scroll

Tags: javascript, css

For a mobile web application, upon a certain user action (e.g. photo upload), I render a translucent overlay with a preloader to cover the screen.

However, I found that id one scrolls, the overlay does't cover the scrolled area. A good workaround for me has been adding `document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';` when the over+preloader renders. Subsequently, I do `document.body.style.overflow = 'visible';` once the preloader ends (e.g. at the completion of the Ajax request).

My problem is that the overlay+preloader attaches at the top of the screen (due to `position:absolutel;top:0;`). If the screen is somewhat scrolled, *the pair still attache to the very top*, leaving some parts uncovered.

I thought I could change `position` to `relative` for both the preloader and the overlay in order to fix this problem. Unfortunately, that causes them to entirely disappear.

How do I ensure the overlay+preloader pair covers the entire screen, even if the said screen is somewhat scrolled?

---

Here's how the CSS looks:

```
<!-- overlay -->
.ld_ol{
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  opacity:0.6;
  z-index:100;
  background-color:#FFFFFF;
}   

<!-- preloader -->
.load{
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  z-index:101;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
}
.load hr{border:0;margin:0;width:40%;height:40%;position:absolute;border-radius:50%;animation:spin 2s ease infinite}

.load :first-child{background:#6092F8;animation-delay:-1.5s}
.load :nth-child(2){background:#FFD332;animation-delay:-1s}
.load :nth-child(3){background:#00F5BB;animation-delay:-0.5s}
.load :last-child{background:#DD2E44}

@keyframes spin{
  0%,100%{transform:translate(0)}
  25%{transform:translate(160%)}
  50%{transform:translate(160%, 160%)}
  75%{transform:translate(0, 160%)}
}
```

Here's how I'm using pure JS to call the overlay+preloader:

```
function personal_group_preloader(action) { 
  if (action=='create') {
    var overlay = document.createElement('div');
    var preloader = document.createElement('div');
    overlay.id = "personal_group_overlay";
    overlay.className = 'ld_ol';
    preloader.id = "personal_group_preloader";
    preloader.className = 'load';
    preloader.innerHTML = '<hr/><hr/><hr/><hr/>';
    document.body.appendChild(preloader);
    document.body.appendChild(overlay);
    document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
  } else {
    var overlay = document.getElementById("personal_group_overlay");
    var preloader = document.getElementById("personal_group_preloader");
    overlay.parentNode.removeChild(overlay);
    preloader.parentNode.removeChild(preloader);
    document.body.style.overflow = 'visible';
  }
}
```

*Note: My first priority is to accomplish this via traditional CSS, instead of venturing into JS.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question you want to overlay the entire screen regardless of screen height. If so use

```
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
height: 100%;
width: 100%
```

If I've misunderstood, let me know.

From the [MSDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position):
Fixed - The element is removed from the normal document flow; no space is created for the element in the page layout. Instead, it is positioned relative to the screen's viewport and doesn't move when scrolled.

Comment: This worked, I'll mark it correct in a bit. Can you tell me why `position:fixed` works?

Comment: You can think of fixed sticking the element in place in the browser window. While an absolute position locks an element to a part of page only.

Answer (score 1):

```
.over-lay{
z-index:2;
position: fixed;
display:block;
top: 0;
left: 0;
height: 100vh;
width: 100vw;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

this css element should cover entire screen regardless of its size z-index + display:block will make sure it stays on top of other elements

Comment: Would be great if you added some explanation as well Eddie